# How to concat alias field in Mybatis using param #{}

Tags: mysql, mybatis

I use springboot and mybatis 3.4.4 and Mysql 5.7, in mybatis mapper, i need to change sql param `${}` to `#{}`,
my sql like that :

```
select * from t1 as record
<if test="orderBy != null and sort != null">
order by
vr.${orderBy} ${sort}
</if>
```

`orderBy` is one field that need to be sorted by, and `sort` is `desc` or `asc`

I need to change `${}` to `#{}` to prevent sql injection, so i try that;

```
select * from t1 as record
<if test="orderBy != null and sort != null">
            order by concat('vr.', #{orderBy})
            <if test="'desc'.equalsIgnoreCase(sort)">
                desc
            </if>
            <if test="'asc'.equalsIgnoreCase(sort)">
                asc
            </if>
        </if>
```

I print the sql and it's correct, the compiled sql like that:

```
select * from t1 as record
order by
concat('vr.', ?) desc
```

But, it doesn't work that it doesn't sort by `sortBy` field, then i do a test on a simple test table in DataGrip, if i input param using quote, it won't work, **i suspect that the param input into mybatis is a string with quote, not the value itself.**

[image]

**Question**: How to solve that to let sort work.

Comment: "But, it doesn't work" -- do you get an error?

Comment: @TheImpaler not an error,  but the result doesn't sorted by the target field

Answer (score 1):

JDBC drivers can **apply** parameters at a limited number of points in the SQL statement, and each database/driver allows different locations for them. The place where the parameter is is not a typical place for a parameter, so the support for it may be sketchy.

To be on the safe side I typically do:

```
select * 
from t1 as record
<if test="orderBy != null and sort != null">
  order by
  <choose>
    <when test="orderBy = 'id'">id</when>
    <when test="orderBy = 'name'">name</when>
    <when test="orderBy = 'address'">address</when>
    <otherwise>status</otherwise>
  </choose>
  <if test="'desc'.equalsIgnoreCase(sort)">desc</if>
</if>
```